# How to connect with microstrategy command manager using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, microstrategy

As i am new to microstrategy i need to know whether it is possible to handle Microstrategy command manager utility using C#.If possible can anyone show me the path to kick start that.

Comment: how about to use CM from command line? Can this be a solution for you?

Comment: Thanks mucio. But i need to do that from my .net environment.

Comment: In the past I saw two solution to automate tasks with MicroStrategy, or a software (java or .Net) which interact with the MicroStrategy SDK or a software that builds a CM script and pass it to the CM command line utility. I never checked if installing CM you get also a DLL that you can reference and use.